# Develop Mobile Web app using Dojox

Tags: dojo

I am new to Dojo. Dojo provides a way to develop Web app for mobiles.
   Just I want to create Hello world app with Dojo.
   Any one help me????

Answer (score 0):

look at this resources, i think it will be helpful

1. Dojox.mobile [test pages](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.5.0/dojo-release-1.5.0/dojox/mobile/tests/) - Several samples showing how to use various features of dojox.mobile.
2. Dojox.mobile [Documentation](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/mobile)
3. [API Reference](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/mobile.html) for dojox.mobile
4. [Instructions](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html) for installing and configuring the Android Device Emulator. You can use the emulator to test the application if you don't have access to an Android device.
5. Visit the [Safari Reference Guide](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/internetweb/conceptual/iPhoneWebAppHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007900-CH1-SW1) or tips on building web applications on the iPhone